# Using overflow:auto on a container to contain long paragraphs of text

Tags: css, overflow

I've got a container with 10px padding all round. It has a set height on it and overflow:auto in order to contain the 'description' which can be as much as 1000 characters long.

Here is what it looks like with no overflow...

[image]

And here it is with a overflow:auto on the container.

[image]

This adds a scrollbar which is the desired effect. However, despite there being 10px of padding on the bottom of the container, the text continues to the very bottom of the containers edge, suggesting that padding isn't taken into account when overflowing. I've tried adding more padding but as expected it makes no difference.

Here is the HTML...

```
<div class="journix-info-inner input-container shadow-bottom">
        <div class="info-header">
                <h2 class="journix-title">
                         <?php echo $row['title']; ?>
                </h2>
                <h3 class="journix-user">
                         by <?php echo $row['user_id']; ?>
                </h3>
         </div>
         <p class="info-content">
                <?php echo $row['description']; ?>
         </p>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS...

```
.journix-info-inner {
    margin-right:310px;
    max-height:360px;
    overflow:auto;
    padding:10px;
}
```

This screenshot shows the padding and how the text is overlapping the bottom 10px of padding.

[image]

Comment: Please post a code snippet or a fiddle in your question.

Comment: Do you mean you want the padding to apply to the box boundaries, clipping the overflow at where that padding would be?

Comment: Yeah, see the screenshot above, you can see that the text clips in to the 10px of padding at the bottom. It's a strange one.

Comment: That's not strange at all - padding is meant to apply beyond the edge of the content. If the content is overflowing then the padding has to follow suit (unless `overflow` is set to `visible`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to set a <section> or <article> element around the text within the container.  You can add a class of your choice, then move the overflow and max-height properties to said element.  You will then be able to use margin in place of padding to maintain whitespace across the bottom:

```
.description {
    max-height: 360px;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

[Example in practice](http://jsfiddle.net/PRNTR/3/)

If you choose to leave the title / subtitle outside of this nested element, this method will have the added benefit of keeping your title and subtitle in place as you scroll :-)

Comment: I've given this a go but the new containing element around the body text still expands beyond the overall container.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention you need to put move the height into the new nested element as well.  Should work with that.  Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/PRNTR/1/.  If you prefer divs, just replace the article and section elements respectively.  Either way, you'd probably want to add classes and identify them that way.

Comment: Thanks very much, unfortunately setting a specific height on the text seems to be the only way to do what I want.

Comment: Do you mean that you would prefer to have it max out at 360px high, but scale back if the article is shorter?  If so, you could replace height with max-height like so: http://jsfiddle.net/PRNTR/3/.  I'm actually having a lot of fun with this one, so let me know.

Comment: Setting a max-height is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect this addition and (hopefully) add a little clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You can try including the [`box-sizing`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0) property to constrain the padding and border to the elements width and height ..

```
.test {
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```